# WIndow's ssh service defaults to admin permission

Tags: windows, ssh, permissions, admin, openssh

Connecting remotely into a windows machine using the OpenSSH service provided by windows always starts an elevated session.
Is it possible to start a non elevated session and elevate after the fact? if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this github discussion: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1652
bagajjal:

> For admin users, ssh connection is an elevated session. Given you are
> an admin and has elevated session, you can write to c:\windows.
>
> This is by design.

jborean93:

> The biggest issue when you were to use the limited token after an SSH
> logon is that you cannot then get your elevated token. On an
> interactive logon you can right click and say Run as administrator and
> confirm through the UAC prompt but on a network logon like SSH there
> is no way for UAC to prompt you. So if this was a functionality you
> will never be able to swap from the limited to full token of your
> admin account.